# ProgressBar Style/Theme Android

Tags: android

After modifying the theme for my Activity to display an ActionBar (ActionBarSherlock to be precise), my progress bar changed from:

[image]

to:

[image]

(Thin blue line).  I need to be able to define the height of the progressbar, which I can't with the Holo theme. How can I specify a theme for my progress bar that's not the same as my activity or what's the other way to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per i know, You are implementing Android inbuilt progressbar which appear the different in different devices and as per then android version.

If you want to implement the Same for all Devices then put make the custom progressbar. Which appear same for all.

Hope it will help you.

Enjoy.

:)